# programming R using ifelse with multiple conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements

an you help me .

i have data.frame E with four columns 
i use only basic package in R 
i do not use for- loop
i have milion rows

```
 phone<-c(123,123,123,333,333,333,456,456,456,789,789,789,500,500,500,....etc) time<-c(2018-11-06,2018-11-06,2018-11-06,2018-11-09,2018-11-09,2018-11-09,2018-11-07,2018-11-07,2018-11-07,2018-11-05,2018-11-05,2018-11-05,2018-11-06,2018-11-06,2018-11-06...etc) 
    tel<-c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,...etc)       
    porad<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3....etc)
```

i want to create new columns with results

E$de<-c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,...etc)

so i used loop and the process ran probably 4 hours.

```
E$de[1]=ifelse(E$phone[i]==E$phone[i+1] & E$time[i]==E$time[i+1] & E$porad[1]==2 & E$tel[1]==1,1,0)
E$de[2]=ifelse(E$phone[i]==E$phone[i+1] & E$time[i]==E$time[i+1] & E$porad[2]==3 & E$tel[2]==1,1,0)
for (i in 3:length(E$phone))
{
  E$de[i]<-ifelse(E$phone[i]==E$phone[i-2] & E$time[i]==E$time[i-2] & E$porad[i]==3 & E$tel[i]==1 & E$tel[i-1]==0 & E$tel[i-2]==0,1,0)
}
```

please help me :D

Comment: There were some suggestions made to you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612935/programming-r-ifelse-loop ...Did you try that ?

Comment: it is not suggestions

Comment: i know that is similar as well with 2 rows , but i do not know add thirth row

Comment: For calculating `E$de[1]=...` and `E$de[2]=...` the object `i` is not defined. Please make your example reproducible!

Comment: You should try doing this with "apply" functions. These are vectorised and fast in R. Have you tried running the code on a subset of the data to make sure it works as expected? If possible, please post a minimal example that can actually be run to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: what is a minimal example . how many rows ?

Comment: @dado For minimal example data copy the output of `dput(head(E, 20))` in your question. Also edit your code: the object `i` has no value before the loop, but are using `i` in the calculation of `E$de[1]` and `E$de[2]`; that will cause an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the loop or the apply statement by vectorizing the `ifelse` statement.

If you define `i` as the vector from 3:length(E$phone), you can then run the ifelse statement directly.

```
#test data
phone<-c(123,123,123,333,333,333,456,456,456,789,789,789,500,500,500)
time<-c("2018-11-06","2018-11-06","2018-11-06","2018-11-09","2018-11-09","2018-11-09",
        "2018-11-07","2018-11-07","2018-11-07","2018-11-05","2018-11-05", "2018-11-05", 
        "2018-11-06","2018-11-06","2018-11-06")
time<-as.Date(time)
tel<-c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
porad<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
E<-data.frame(phone, time, tel, porad)

E$de[1]=ifelse(E$phone[1]==E$phone[2] & E$time[1]==E$time[2] & E$porad[1]==2 & E$tel[1]==1,1,0)
E$de[2]=ifelse(E$phone[2]==E$phone[3] & E$time[2]==E$time[3] & E$porad[2]==3 & E$tel[2]==1,1,0)

#vectorized ifelse statement
i<-3:length(E$phone)
E$de[i]<-ifelse(E$phone[i]==E$phone[i-2] & E$time[i]==E$time[i-2] & E$porad[i]==3 & E$tel[i]==1 & E$tel[i-1]==0 & E$tel[i-2]==0,1,0)
```

This should run approximately 1000x faster than the for loop.